# Then what is the probability that out of $n$ men $A_1,A_2,....,A_n$ each aged $x$ years,$A_1$ will die and will be the first to die

Tags: probability

Let $p$ be the probability that a man aged $x$ years will die in a year time.Then what is the probability that out of $n$ men $A_1,A_2,....,A_n$ each aged $x$ years,$A_1$ will die and will be the first to die?

The probability that a man aged $x$ years will die in a year time$=p$

The probability that a man aged $x$ years will not die in a year time$=1-p$

But from here on,i got stuck.Some hints and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The question is most unclear (see below to see users trying to determine what is actually asked).

Comment: Why downvote members,this is complete question given in my book.

Comment: The problem is solved clearly here in page 401 - Example 58 of this book:https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=GliVtKqkKgwC&pg=PA401&lpg=PA401&dq=Let+p+be+the+probability+that+a+man+aged+xx+years+will+die+in+a+year+time.&source=bl&ots=-WQgIQtu3k&sig=9ldwZh2efJJPtTcJva2ZsFN2yrI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMI4oiOu4OXyAIVS9YUCh1k5g5Q#v=onepage&q=Let%20p%20be%20the%20probability%20that%20a%20man%20aged%20xx%20years%20will%20die%20in%20a%20year%20time.&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

I preassume that your looking for the probability that $A_1$ will die *within a year* and that he also will be the first to die. Secondly I preassume that all men have equal chances when it comes to dying.

Let $E$ denote the event that within a year at least one of the men will die. Let $D_i$ denote the event that $A_i$ will be the first man that dies. Then you are looking for $P(D_1\cap E)$.

Note that $P(D_i\cap E)$ will not depend on $i$ so that: $$nP(D_1\cap E)=P(D_1\cap E)+\cdots+P(D_n\cap E)=P(E)$$

Can you find $P(E)$? Then you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

Probability that $A_k$ is dead  $=$ $p$

Probability that $A_k$ is not dead in one year  $=$ $1-p$

Probability that from $A_1,A_2,A_3...A_n $ no one dies in one year $=$ $(1-p)^{n} $ $=$ $P_1$ $(Let)$

Now, the probability that exactly one man dies in that year is $ = 1-$ $P_1$

$=$ $1-(1-p)^{n} = P_2 (Let)$

Now, the probability that from $n$ men, $A_1$ dies is $ \frac {P_2} n$

This implies $P(E)$,where $E$ is the event that $A_1$ is dead in one year and is the first to die is

$P(E)=$ $ \frac{1-(1-p)^n}{n} $

Comment: You calculate the probability that $A_1$ dies within a year and the others do not. But $A_1$ can also be the first to die if he is not the only that dies within a year. It can even happen that $A_1$ does not die within a year (let's hope so).

Comment: $\frac{1-(1-p)^n}{n}$ is the given answer in the book.

Comment: You need to review this answer as I see it has several errors, e.g. If P(A1) is dead = p is not related to the following deductions.